# Viewing matplotlib output via SSH

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, x11

Python X11 OSX forward? I am SSHing to a remote server (IMAC high sierra) from my macbook pro (high sierra) via XQuartz:

```
ssh -X me@hostname
```

and run remotely a Python script on the host. However, the generated figures from matplotlib.plot can not show on the client (my macbook pro).

How could I fix this ?

Comment: Have you set your X11 forwarding? In your ssh_config file (typically found in /etc/ssh directory), you'll need to check for a line that might say:  "#  ForwardX11 no" If there is such a line, uncomment it and change the 'no' to a 'yes'. In any case, this is not a Python issue. It's an OS/system/X type of issue.

Comment: Start by trying something simple like `xclock` or a trivial `Tkinter` program.

Comment: xclock/xeyes works fine. I don't install Tkinter though. Thus I guess it would be a problem associated with Python